# VBA macro to open Mozilla Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, firefox

Hi I have come up with a code, which will open Internet Explorer, navigate to a website, enter user id and password and finally click the login button.

The code is:

```
Public Sub LOGIN()

    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 
    Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With objIE
        .Navigate "https://website.co.in" ' Main page
        .Visible = 1
        Do While .READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

        Set htmlDoc = .document
        Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
        Do While htmlDoc.READYSTATE <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.Name = "UserName" Or htmlInput.Type = "text" Then
                htmlInput.Value = "Adidas"
            Else
               If htmlInput.Name = "password" Then
                 htmlInput.Value = "Daddy123"

                End If
            End If
        Next htmlInput

        Set htmlDoc = .document
        Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        Do While htmlDoc.READYSTATE <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
                htmlInput.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next htmlInput
    End With
End Sub
```

But as the website for which I have created this script doesn't support Internet Explorer I want to open the same in Firefox. I am clueless and I have not tried anything so far. Please help me out.

Comment: Sadly yes :( I have no idea how to go about this

Comment: Let's go back to the original problem. You say the website doesn't support Internet Explorer? So what's wrong with it? (With the website, that is.)

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to store a password unencrypted in a plain text file?

Comment: This code is mine but i dont know how to lanch Firefox.

Comment: Yes Mr. Lister. The website was working fine in IE but recently changes has been made on this website and it only works on Firefox.

Comment: @user2165404 - Have a look at this post http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?640202-VBScript-to-start-Firefox-with-profile or http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/vbscript-to-start-firefox-with-profile/24196.html#postfp

Comment: @DaveRook He wants to automate the page in Firefox, not only launch it in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox does not expose a COM object, so it can't be controlled the way IE can be controlled. You may be able to achieve your goal with some other automation tool, though, e.g. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Another option may be to sniff the authentication traffic (i.e. the communication that takes place when you click the "login" button) with something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) and then use VBScript to automate the login with an [XMLHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx):

```
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "POST", "http://www.example.org/", False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send "field1=foo&field2=bar&..."
```