# Post data with https does not get processed at Server side

Tags: vbscript

I am having a VBScript which gets invoked from a 3rd party application, the script gets the data from the 3rd party application and opens the URL in an IE browser by passing the data in POST format. The script works fine when I use http as the protocol but the moment I use https, the server side code (request.getParameter("param1")) complains that it is not able to find the parameter in the request object. The script is called by passing the URL and the data. e.g. run.vbs https://xyz.com?param1=1234. Following is the vbscript for your kind perusal. Can you please let me know what I am missing when I am using https as the protocol. Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
uri = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
'WScript.Echo "Arguments " & uri
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
'WScript.Echo "Current User Name: " & WshNetwork.UserName
filename="C:\Documents and Settings\"+WshNetwork.UserName+"\Application Data\XYZ\Profiles\default\Settings.xml"
'WScript.Echo "Current User fileName: " & filename

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load(filename)
strQuery = "Agent"
Set colItem = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagname(strQuery)
For Each objItem in colItem
    Agentid = objItem.getAttribute("Login")
    'MsgBox "AgentId = " + AgentID
Next

'uri = uri+"^&agentid="+Agentid
uri = uri+"&agentid="+Agentid
pos = InStr(uri,"?")
extracteduri = Mid(uri,1,pos-1)
params = Mid(uri, pos+1)
postdata = Str2Bytes(params,"us-ascii")
header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'IE.Navigate "about:blank"
'IE.AddressBar = True
'IE.ToolBar = True
'IE.StatusBar = True
IE.Visible = True
'WScript.Sleep 2000
Set shl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shl.SendKeys "% X" 
IE.Navigate extracteduri, Nothing, Nothing, postdata, header
Wscript.Quit
 Else
Wscript.Echo "Usage: RunURL.vbs <URL to invoke>"
Wscript.Quit
 End If
 Function Str2Bytes(Text, CharSet)
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adTypeBinary = 1

  'Create Stream object
  Dim BinaryStream 'As New Stream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText

  'Specify charset For the source text (unicode) data.
  If Len(CharSet) > 0 Then
    BinaryStream.CharSet = CharSet
  Else
    BinaryStream.CharSet = "us-ascii"
  End If

  'Open the stream And write text/string data To the object
  BinaryStream.Open
  BinaryStream.WriteText Text

  'Change stream type To binary
  BinaryStream.Position = 0
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  'Ignore first two bytes - sign of
  BinaryStream.Position = 0

  'Open the stream And get binary data from the object
  Str2Bytes = BinaryStream.Read
End Function
```

I am now using the below function to get the response from the server using https as the protocol and POST as the format but still the server is not able to see the parameter

```
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
'Set the below option to get rid of the "Certificate authority is invalid or     
     'incorrect, error code - 80072F0D" error
req.setOption 2, 13056
req.open "POST", extracteduri, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
encodedParams = Escape(params)
WScript.Echo "encodedParams: " & encodedParams
req.send encodedParams
WScript.Echo "req.responseText: " & req.responseText
```

Below are the encoded parameters
uui%3DU1%3D123456%26agentid%3D123456

The server still complains that the parameter is missing from the request object.

I am using the same script (XMLHTTP request) but I am encrypting the parameters using the Str2Bytes function (declared above)

```
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
req.setOption 2, 13056
req.open "POST", extracteduri, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send postdata
WScript.Echo "req.responseText: " & req.responseText
```

Comment: please help me as I have to resolve this issue on an urgent basis.

Comment: You should encode the parameter *values*, not the entire parameter string. Since the string decodes to `uui=U1=123456&agentid=123456`, it should probably be encoded like this: `uui=U1%3D123456&agentid=123456`. And I still don't see a parameter `param1` in your parameter string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an [`XMLHTTPRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx) instead of the Internet Explorer COM object. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636155/1630171) for an example. Note that you must [encode](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) special characters in the post data.

However, if you want to open the URL in IE anyway, you'd probably better stick with your original approach. In that case I'd check the server for more information about why the server side thinks it cannot find the parameter. Does the request even have a parameter named `"param1"`?

Comment: Hello Ansgar, will it open the url with the post data in an IE browser?

Comment: You can launch an IE instance and insert the response into a blank page, but it won't automatically be displayed in IE.

Comment: Do you have any sample vbscript which uses XMLHTTPRequest to post data to a server, basically I want to open the URL in an IE browser

Comment: I linked to a sample in my answer. However, if you want to open the URL in IE anyway, you probably should stick with your original approach. See updated answer.

Comment: My vbs script is able to receive the response from the server but how do I display the same in an IE browser? Please help

Comment: Hello Ansgar Wiechers, Thanks for your response, basically I want open an URL in a browser by passing the data in POST format but the above script does not work with https as the protocol

Comment: I tried using the XMLHTTPRequest object to send the request parameters to the server but still the server is not able to see the request parameters. I have added the code in the main question section

Comment: I am able to see the response from the server using the XMLHTTpRequest, the server is sending a valid response but when it comes to loading the url (POST) in an IE browser it does not seem to work, please help

Comment: How exactly does it "not seem to work"? Show the code you're using now. Show the request you're sending. And show the error you're getting (on client **and** server).

Comment: The problem was with the website's certificate, seems like if the server's certificate is not added to the IE's trusted store, it gives this error